# FB comment plugin: User Notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Users on my website can create their own content pages and I want to enable FB comment plugin on those pages. As a moderator of the FB app, I get the notifications but is there a way the user who created that content page on my website get notified if there is a new comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking for the same feature. 
I think you would have to subscribe to the following event and handle the notification process yourself.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function() {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, will have to go with what you suggested!